# Convert project to Require JS from Inject JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I have been using Inject JS for my projects for a while.  I like inject, but our current project needs to be extra speedy. I played around with various dependency management libraries and found that Require won the speed contest.  The biggest obstacle that I have is all of our require declarations in inject use "." instead of "/".  So the paths look like this.

```
var myModule = require("folder.folder.folder.javascript");
```

or

```
var appNavModel = require("com.project.component.appNavModel");
```

Is there a way to use requirejs.config to find those modules?  I can get my hands dirty and modify the library, but I figured I should ask first.

Comment: If you are committed to migrating from one dependency manager to another, is it really that much work to update the dependency statements? Seems like you could get most of the way there with a pretty simple regex search&replace.

Comment: Just a warning: If this is browser-based (and not say, nodejs-based) JavaScript, that's not the only big thing you'll have to change. The `var x = require('y')` model is synchronous, which I believe usually you don't want in a client-based scenario.

Comment: @Katana314 no it isn't

Comment: Mathletics, If the project was small, I would so do that. I was just hoping for as little change as possible to the project to avoid bugs.

Comment: I would recommend not migrating at all; I am highly dubious of the value. What does Require get you in terms of speed that Inject doesn't?

Comment: Size adds up with web applications.  This is no mere web page.  I have already tossed jquery and Greensock, and I love Greensock. This will buy me about another 50kb, and faster xhr returns.

Comment: If you are worried about runtime size, you should be looking at Webpack, not Require.

Comment: Regarding the original question, I don't understand why your dependencies are written that way? I can't find anything in the Inject docs to support that syntax.

Comment: They are written that way because my boss wanted it that way.   So thus it it shall be.  With inject its easy to work around with a quick addFileRule

Comment: I will look at webpack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94981/discussion-between-mardok-and-mathletics).